# No puedo iniciar GlassFish en NetBeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

Tengo instalado Windows 10, JDK 8.211 y NetBeans 8.2, al iniciar GlassFish en NetBeans, me presenta el siguiente mensaje :

***No se ha podido recibir en el puerto 1527 en el host localhost:***

En otra PC más viejita, instalé lo mismo y puedo iniciar el servicio sin problema.

Alguien puede decirme como resolverlo ?

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Para encontrar el proceso que mantiene el puerto ocupado, pruebe el siguiente comando:

> ```
> netstat -ano | find "1527"
> ```

2. Esto mostrará una línea con el puerto y el identificador del proceso. p.ej.:

> ```
> TCP    127.0.0.1:1527         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2268
> ```

3. Una vez que tenga el ID de proceso (por ejemplo, 2268), ejecute el siguiente comando para liberar el puerto (esto anulará el proceso):

> `taskkill /F /PID 2268`

4. Ahora, trata de iniciar Glassfish.

Comment: Gracias Gabriel, con tu ayuda pude ya resolverlo.

Comment: @CesarColín Me alegro que te haya servido amigo! Saludos